# Ionic Angular Project version compatibility issue with PHP

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework, composer-php

Ionic angular project issue with version compatibility.
I am trying to run an existing ionic angular project by running this command `composer install` and get this error

```
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - facebook/graph-sdk is locked to version 5.7.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - facebook/graph-sdk 5.7.0 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros is locked to version 2.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.6.0 requires php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 3.4.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.4.5 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - tymon/jwt-auth is locked to version 1.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.1 requires php ^5.5.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - phpspec/prophecy is locked to version 1.13.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpspec/prophecy 1.13.0 requires php ^7.2 || ~8.0, <8.1 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.6.0 requires php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/passport v9.4.0 requires laminas/laminas-diactoros ^2.2 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-diactoros[2.6.0].
    - laravel/passport is locked to version v9.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

I have currently php version 8.2.6 installed on my machine.

I tried to run the `composer update` which resulted another error as below

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.3.13 but your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires facebook/graph-sdk 5.7.0 -> satisfiable by facebook/graph-sdk[5.7.0].
    - facebook/graph-sdk 5.7.0 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.1 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[1.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.1 requires php ^5.5.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Comment: _"Root composer.json requires php ^7.3.13 but your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement."_ - so you would need to switch to PHP 8 in your root composer.json to begin with But that won't help you either, because then you'd still be dealing with the fact that the Facebook SDK requires `^5.4|^7.0`.

Comment: The FacebookPHP SDK is marked as "abandoned" on packagist.org, and the github page says it was archived on Jan 13, 2022. So you won't be able to get this to work by using any official package repository, I suppose. You could download the SDK and put it somewhere locally, so that you can modify it's PHP version requirements; after that, you might be able to install it from a local repo via composer then. But whether the SDK itself will even _run_ properly under PHP 8, is still not a given then.

Comment: What if I reduce my PHP version from 8.2.6 to some lower version that support these composer libs ?

Comment: @AliAkram I think with PHP 7.3 it's all gonna work

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP 7.4 is EOL since Nov 2022, which means that you should plan upgrading your application to PHP 8 in the near future. Relying on libraries that require PHP 7 is not a good idea